# can I remove or change background color subtitle/webvtt in html5

Tags: html5-video, background-color, subtitle, webvtt, video-subtitles

I want to remove or change the background of the subtitles. I've changed the background-color and background but it doesn't work. can the background change?

```
::cue {
  color: red;
  background-color: blue; //or background: blue;
}
```

the subtitle color changes to red but the background doesn't change at all

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following:

```
::cue {
  color: red;
  // take an absurd big outline, because background is only behind the text
  outline: 500px solid blue;
  // dont know why background-color is not working but background-image does the job
  background-image: linear-gradient(blue, blue);
}
```

Comment: is there any way to remove background subtitle??